# Are there drawbacks to use arrow functions in classes

Tags: typescript

When writing a Typescript class such as this:

```
class Foo {
  bar() { }
}
```

It's sometimes helpful to rewrite this as:

```
class Foo {
  bar = () => { }
}
```

Primary reason is that I can pass bar as a callback to something else, but retain the `this` reference.

This feels a bit 'weird' however. Functions and properties have their own syntax, and using property syntax for a function feels like I'm doing the wrong thing.

The benefits are obvious though. *Usually* you would want `this` to refer to the current instance of the class, so in that respect it feels like it should probably by the default / sane behavior *unless* you want `this` to be re-associated explicitly. That situation is so rare though, that if I wanted to use this behavior I would probably keep those functions outside of classes altogether.

So my question is.. are there good reasons to *not* do this? Should we just always be using arrow functions and opt-out of rebinding `this` unless this is explicitly desired?

Comment: I think you mean `bar = `, otherwise you're just *typing* it. In TypeScript that's converted to `this.bar = () => {}` in the constructor: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYGwhgzhAEBiD29oG8BQ1oCMwCdoF5oAKASgID4VoBfVWoA.

Comment: @jonrsharpe, yes! fixed

Comment: I think this is a JavaScript question (ES2015+) and has little to do with TypeScript specifically, right?

Comment: @jcalz looks like EcmaScript field declarations are still very much experimental, so I'm sticking with the typescript label.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Keeping `this` the same regardless of calling syntax is one of the reasons you *should* use arrow functions. The `bar = () => { }` is the syntax precisely for your use case.

But there are some difference that might matter.

```
class Foo {
  bar() { }
}
```

This creates one function, just once, and puts it on `Foo.prototype.bar`, and it is bound purely by calling syntax `foo.bar()`. This is fast and memory efficient.

```
class Foo {
  bar = () => { }
}
```

This creates the function in the constructor, and binds `this` to the instance, regardless of how the function is called. This is slower, and each instance now has a unique function object in memory it has to keep track of.

If you are creating huge numbers of instances of this class, and performance is important to your project, you *may* start having memory issues since the memory footprint of each instance is higher.

---

That said, premature optimization is the root of all evil. Use whichever is easier for you, unless your are doing expensive processing of tens of thousands of instances of your class at a time.